# COMBINAR ARRAY con 3 valores

Tags: php, array

tengo una consulta y es que no logro armar un arreglo con 3 valores. Necesito acomodarlos de la siguiente manera:

> - Producto 1
> - Unidades
> - Precio

> - Producto 2
> - Unidades
> - Precio

Tengo el siguiente código

```
public function addPaymentDev() {

    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $item_selected = array();
    $quantity = array();
    $category_selected = array();
    $precio_modificado = array();        
    $category_selected = $this->input->post('category_name');
    $item_selected = $this->input->post('category_id');
    $quantity = $this->input->post('quantity');
    $precio_modificado = $this->input->post('precio');
    $remarks = $this->input->post('remarks');
    $pagoen = $this->input->post('pagoen');
    
    $subtotaldev = $this->input->post('subtotal');

    if (empty($item_selected)) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('feedback', lang('select_an_item'));
        redirect('finance/addPaymentViewDev');
    } else {
        $item_quantity_array = array();
        $item_quantity_array = array_combine($item_selected, $quantity);
                                
    }
    $cat_and_price = array();
    $count = 0;
    if (!empty($item_quantity_array)) {
        foreach ($item_quantity_array as $key => $value) {
                            
                $current_item = $this->finance_model->getPaymentCategoryById($key);
                $category_price = $current_item->c_price;
                $category_type = $current_item->category;
                $cabys = $current_item->CABYS; //Cabys
                $qty = $value;
                $cat_and_price[] = $key . '*' . $category_price . '*' . $category_type . '*' . $qty . '*' . $cabys; //Aqui puedo meterle el impuesto correspondiente para luego sumarlo.
                $amount_by_category[] = $category_price * $qty;
                $count = $count + 1;
        }
        $category_name = implode(',', $cat_and_price);
    } else {
        //$this->session->set_flashdata('feedback', lang('attend_the_required_fields'));
        $this->session->set_flashdata('feedback', 'Error 01');
        redirect('finance/addPaymentViewDev');
    }
```

> Lo que necesito es que la variable **$category_price** muestre el valor de ***$precio_modificado*** para cada producto añadido.

He intentado en agregar en el arreglo, este tercer valor (**$precio_modificado**):

`$item_quantity_array = array_combine($item_selected, $quantity, $precio_modificado);`

Pero falla porque se sale en el Else que reporta el Error 01; o puede ser que no encuentro la manera correcta de usar esa variable con *$category_price*

¿Me podrían ayudar?
Muchísimas gracias de antemano

Comment: No entiendo mucho ni el problema ni el código. En el `else` defines el array cada vez, ¿por qué?  ¿El problema cuál es? ¿Qué obtienes? ¿Qué esperas obtener? ¿Qué has depurado? ¿Con qué resultados? ¿Tus datos vienen de una base de datos (de ser así podrías traerlos ordenados desde la consulta SQL)? Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano gracias, Lo que necesito es que la variable $category_price muestre el valor de $precio_modificado para cada producto añadido.

En el post, comenté que trate de hacer un array con 3 valores pero se sale con el error 01 que detallo en el código

Comment: Si *se sale* con ese error es porque `$item_quantity_array` está vacío y si eso ocurre es quizá porque `$item_selected` no está vacío. Es lo que se logra descifrar en la lógica de tu código. Depura tus variables y casi seguro encontrarás lo que está fallando. Empieza por depurar a `$item_selected`